# Weird IE8 CSS/HTML bug when using Yahoo's YUI Uploader

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, yui

This video explains the problem best: http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cQ1Oc9f1L

Basically the directory is located here: http://www.ipalaces.org/uploaderprogress/grrrrrr.html

Is the problem piece using YUI.js as the uploading script. The YUI updates the table's row with new information on every event. So I have it update it with some CSS/HTML so that it does a progress loading bar. It works fine for all browsers but IE. I am not sure if this is a known rendering bug or what, and if there is even a fix for it?

the working-demo.html basically shows that if you just resize the div using javascript, IE renders it fine. Its just updated the table's row with new div information seems to cause rendering issues.

Edit: I would link everything but I can only use 1 hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

If I include this in the HTML then it will work fine:

```
<div class='progressbar-completed' style='visibility: hidden;'></div>
```

It seems like IE is having trouble maintaining the "memory" of the background file when its dynamically created in javascript.

Putting the DIV in the html itself seems to make the memory of the background file persistent in IE.